# Conditional probability of playing a game

Tags: probability, markov-chains

> A game wins you \$1 with probability 0.6 and takes away \$1 with probability 0.4. The game stops when you have won \$4 or lost all your money.
>
> Let $p_n$ be the probability that you acquire \$4 if you start the game with \$n, where $n = 1,2,3$. Using the conditional probability given the result of the ﬁrst game, express $p_2$ in terms of $p_1$ and $p_3$.

I know that the conditional probability is equal to
$$\mathsf P(A\mid B)=\frac{\mathsf P(A\bigcap B)}{\mathsf P(B)}$$
and the first time we will stop our game is equal to 0.4 and 0.6 to continue the game but I don't know how to get involve with this to $p_2$. And how to derive three equations with three unknowns $p_1,p_2,p_3$ and calculate  the probabilities?

Comment: $n$ stands for the times that we play the game?

Comment: I think this is a problem of one-step analysis in markov chain

Comment: Re Jimmy Yes sorry for unclear

Comment: What is Markov chain. I have never herd about it

Answer (score 1):

Well, $p_2$ is the probability that you ultimately win if you have $\$2$.

Let $S_2$ be the event of starting with $\$2$.  Let $R_4$ be the event of reaching $\$4$.    Then $p_2=\mathsf P(R_4\mid S_2)$

Condition on the next game you play.

Let $W_n$ be the event of winning the next game.  $\mathsf P(W_n)=0.6$

Then:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(R_4\mid S_2)~=~&\mathsf P(W_n)\,\mathsf P(R_4\mid W_n,S_2)+\mathsf P(W_n^\complement)\,\mathsf P(R_4\mid W_n^\complement,S_2)\\[1ex] ~=~&\mathsf P(W_n)\,\bbox[cornsilk, 1pt,border:solid 1pt lemonchiffon]{\color{cornsilk}{\mathsf P(R_4\mid S_3)}?}+\mathsf P(W_n^\complement)\;\bbox[cornsilk, 1pt,border:solid 1pt lemonchiffon]{\color{cornsilk}{\mathsf P(R_4\mid S_1)}?}\\[1ex] p_2 ~=~&0.6\;\bbox[cornsilk, 1pt,border:solid 1pt lemonchiffon]{\color{cornsilk}{p_3\quad}?}+0.4\;\bbox[cornsilk, 1pt,border: lemonchiffon solid 1pt]{\color{cornsilk}{p_1\quad}?}\end{align}$$

Continue...

Comment: how to write out the conditional prob terms? I got no idea on that terms

Comment: $\mathsf P(R_4\mid W_n, S_2)$ is the probability of reaching $\$4$ given that you have $\$2$ and win the next game.  What happens if you have $\$2$ and win the next game? @Ccnoc

Comment: if I have $2 to and wind the next game I will got $3 but if I lost the game I will back to the origin $1

Comment: @Ccnoc  Exactly.  So what are those probabilities in terms of $p_2, p_3,$ or $p_1$?

Comment: that means $$\mathsf P(R\scriptstyle 4 \textstyle\mid S\scriptstyle 2 ) = \displaystyle P\scriptstyle $$ and  the other terms equal  to p1?

Comment: that means $ \mathsf P(R\scriptstyle 4 \textstyle\mid S\scriptstyle 2 ) = \displaystyle P\scriptstyle 3$ and the other terms equal to p1?

Comment: Yes. @Ccnoc  Well, $\mathsf P(R_4\mid S_3)=p_3$ and $\mathsf P(R_4\mid S_1)=p_1$